# Continuous First order logic vs Second order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, real-numbers, model-theory, second-order-logic

By continuous first order logic I mean first order logic but replace truth values taking on 0 or 1 with the compact set [0,1].

Is continuous first order logic strong enough to make statements about all subsets? Example: every bounded non-empty subset has a supremum.

Is there some trick where this can be done?

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4303.pdf

Comment: $[0, 1]$ is not a Boolean algebra, so I struggle to see how you are going to make even propositional classical logic work.

Comment: @MarkSaving added this reference to the question https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4303.pdf

Comment: What is a structure in continuous logic to you? Usually they are (bounded) complete metric spaces (equipped with some uniformly continuous functions), but complete metric spaces are never countable (in fact they always have cardinality at least $\mathfrak c$)

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti ah duh thank you! I’ll remove question 2 as it takes away from question 1. Still familiarizing myself with continuous logic. Heard of continuous logic from physics as it’s powerful enough to talk about Hilbert spaces and inner product spaces.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Complete bounded metric spaces (even compact metric spaces) **can** be countable - consider $\{{1\over n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber fair enough, but not when they have no isolated points, as should be the case for anything modeling the theory of $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuous logic (as described in [http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~begnac/articles/mtfms.pdf](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/%7Ebegnac/articles/mtfms.pdf), for example) does not allow you to make statements about arbitrary subsets.  There are (at least) two ways that this is true:

1. The quantifiers in continuous logic range over elements of the structure, not over subsets.  Thus there is no direct way that you can say something like $\forall S \subseteq M \ldots$ at all.
2. Given any formula $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ and a structure $\mathcal{M}$ of the appropriate language, the set $\{(a_1, \ldots, a_n) \in M^n : \mathcal{M} \models \varphi(a_1, \ldots, a_n)\}$ is a closed subset of $M^n$.  In this sense the language of continuous logic cannot describe any non-closed set (it can't necessarily describe all closed sets either, nor even properly describe all zerosets, but that's a more subtle matter).

You mentioned order-completeness in the question.  Often you can't even put an ordering into the language (you would have to put the distance to the ordering as a predicate instead, and then uniform continuity requirements will impose some compatibility between the ordering and the metric).

On the other hand, metric completeness (every Cauchy sequence converges) is definitely not expressible in continuous logic.  Indeed, if you have any metric structure $\mathcal{M}$ where the underlying metric space $(M, d)$ is incomplete*, and let $\overline{\mathcal{M}}$ be the (unique, up to isomorphism) extension of $\mathcal{M}$ based on the metric completion of $(M, d)$, then $\mathcal{M} \preceq \overline{\mathcal{M}}$.

*: Usually the term "metric structure" is reserved for structures based on complete metric spaces, so I'm abusing the name a little bit here.  I hope the meaning is clear enough.

Comment: Chris, thank you for your answer! One point. “In almost all treatments of continuous logic the definition of a structure is it is a complete metric space together with interpretations for the symbols of the language. So you don't need to axiomatize completeness, since all the structures you consider are complete”. could this be made true for above order completeness? Baking it into the structure so we don’t need to state it? 

Referencing  your comment on my other question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4524067/continuous-first-order-logic-hilbert-spaces-and-von-neumann-algebras

Comment: You could certainly define a logic where your semantics are restricted to structures based on an ordered set that is order-complete.  The problem is that such a logic is not very well-behaved.  For example, let $DLO$ be the first-order theory expressing that the ordering is a linear order that is endless and dense in itself.  If you restrict to structures based on complete orders then $DLO$ has no countable models (the only countable endless dense-in-itself linear order is the order on $\mathbb{Q}$, which is not complete).  So Lowenheim-Skolem fails for this logic.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I would be careful about saying the Lowenheim-Skolem fails, just because there is no countable structure. Typically metric structures (in continuous logic) have no countable elementary substructure, even in (essentially) countable signatures. This is of course because we ask for completeness. It turns out that the 'right' notion of size is that of density character. So before you claim that LS fails you first need to be sure you are considering the right notion of size. Even then one could argue that if LS holds at some point (i.e. from some cardinal onwards) then that is enough.