# Continuous first order logic, Hilbert spaces and von Neumann algebras

Tags: hilbert-spaces, first-order-logic, model-theory

By continuous first order logic I mean first order logic but replace truth values taking on 0 or 1 with the compact set [0,1] (as is defined in the paper below).

https://arxiv.org/pdf/0801.4303.pdf

1. In continuous FOL is there a complete theory of infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces? In continuous logic there is a complete theory of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (section 15 below).

[https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~henson/cfo/mtfms.pdf](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/%7Ehenson/cfo/mtfms.pdf)

2. Is continuous FOL powerful enough to axiomatize tracial von Neumann algebras? In continuous logic there is an axiomatization of tracial von Neumann algebras (section 5.1 below).

[https://www.math.uci.edu/~isaac/vNanotes.pdf](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Eisaac/vNanotes.pdf)

Comment: It seems like you're making a distinction between "continuous first order logic" and "continuous logic". Can you say precisely what this distinction is? At first glance, all three of the papers you link to seem to be about the same logic.

Comment: @AlexKruckman so that is my confusion. In the answer to a previous question I asked 
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4523819/continuous-first-order-logic-vs-second-order-logic

We have “metric completeness (every Cauchy sequence converges) is definitely not expressible in continuous logic.” FOL is also not strong enough to talk about separability. 

But somehow continuous FOL is strong enough to give a complete theory of infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces as well as W* Algebras? 

 they must use “continuous second order logic”  somewhere?  As hilbert spaces are complete.

Comment: @mark I think the confusion here might be about the definition of the semantic objects.  In almost all treatments of continuous logic (like the ones you linked to) the *definition* of a structure is that it is a *complete* metric space together with interpretations for the symbols of the language.  So you don't need to axiomatize completeness, it's part of the setup of the logic that all the structures you consider are complete.

Comment: I'll add that separability isn't expressible in continuous logic for the same reason that countability isn't expressible in discrete first-order logic: The Lowenheim-Skolem theorems tell you that first-order expressions can't control cardinality (in the metric setting cardinality is replaced by density)